# Are there any references to Gunther or Anna in Deus Ex: Human Revolution?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

I have probably neither read all e-mails/e-books nor visited every spot in Human Revolution, but are there any references to Gunther Hermann or Anna Navarre in this game? The only one I can connect is a conversation between two guards in Tai Yong Medical on the flavor dispensed by the soda machine.

Comment: The 'death-by-vending-machine' skit in China made me think of Gunther's famous vending machine routine, too :]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've read a fair amount of text books and e-mails in the game, and never encountered any reference to Anna Navarre and Gunther Hermann. The "Deus EX: Icarus Effect" novel that has been released several months before "Deus Ex: Human Revolution" discusses the role Gunther Hermann played in some events prior to "Human Revolution" (you can read about it [here](http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/Deus_Ex:_Icarus_Effect)), but nothing more.